# Issue while trying to share io.request.session with passport.session

Tags: node.js, socket.io, passport.js

## My setup:

#### Passport:

Basic serialize, deserialize users :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { //serialize user
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) { // deserialize user
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('There was an error accessing the records of' +
            ' user with id: ' + id);
            return done(err);
        }
        return done(null, user);
    })
});
```

with working local-login.

#### SessionMiddleWareStore and app configuration:

```
sessionStore = new mongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  touchAfter: 24 * 3600});
var sessionMware =  session({
    name: 'socialify.sess', store: sessionStore, secret: sessionSecret, resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true, cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24},
    secret: "eknfdjsnfjsdfn852"
});
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(sessionMware)

io.use(function (socket, next) {
  sessionMware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

#### Server.js (main file):

```
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app)
io.listen(httpsServer);
httpsServer.listen(port, function () {
    return console.log('Socialify server listening on %s at port %d in %s mode', host, port, env);
});
```

## The issue:

I was trying to manage how to share a session between all that stuff (passport, httpRequest and socket.io)
It seems that io well have a session, but not the good one. because :

```
var userSockets = {};
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.request.session) // is ok but doesn't contain passport array.
  var ID = socket.request.session.passport.user; // passport.user undefined.. grrr !
  userSockets[ID] = socket;
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    delete userSockets[ID];
    return console.log('The client has disconnected');
  });
});
```

I need to have this id to acces the socket inside a http request while I'm trying to store all user[id] and export this so that it could be shared.

Answer (score 0):

#### Found the mistake ...

I was storing the passport cookie to www.mydomain.com and the io one to mydomain.com so the middleware created a store for each one...
Now it's solve!